# DbContext onModelCreating filter data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 App in the DBContext class following Code.
DbContext

```
public DbSet<MyTable> MyTable1 { get; set; }
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().ToTable("MyTable");
```

is it correct the `.ToTable` always gets the whole content of the table?
I need only certain data (filter). for example get projects from table Project which employees ID = 4.
The employee ID I have but after successful login. How do I get the data now in my controller class?

Comment: You need to take a step back and re-read how EF6 works. Follow some tutorials, do a plural sight course, something similar. You need to understand some of the *basics* first.

Answer (score 1):

ToTable simply maps the object to the table. Until you request data with a linq statement its not doing anything. When you call ToList on the where clause then you EF will reach out to the database and query returning only the desired results.

All that is is doing is saying that MyTable maps to MyTable in sql. Nothing more.

If you want to specifically filter the entire result set **permanently** you can do so with Eneity.HasQueryFilter(y => y.ID == 4);